# How do you stop changes in a private package from affecting other packages with Melos?

Tags: flutter, dart, package, monorepo, melos

So I am try to consolidate a project to a monorepo using Melos and I'm trying to figure out how, if I'm working in one package and makes some changes, can the other packages remain protected and not break through versioning ideally. I am new to Melos but all I have been able to find is adding this to the bootstrap command

command:
bootstrap:
usePubspecOverrides: false

How do you handle versioning of private packages with Melos? I want to be able to make temporary/experimental changes to a package without affecting packages that depend on it. It seems infeasible without creating our own private pub server, am I missing something?